# %s appearing along with product name

Tags: php, html, magento

I have the following code in a `phtml` file:

```
<div class="actions">
<?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__(" View Details about %s "), $_productNameStripped ?>" class="button"><?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?>
</a>
</div>
```

While hovering the details button of a product it has to show 
View details about (product name)  which is (`%s` is replaced by `$_productNameStripped`).

Actual Result: View Details about `%sProductName`

Expected Result: View Details about `ProductName`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div class="actions">
<?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo sprintf("View Details about %s ",$_productNameStripped) ?>" class="button"><?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?>
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo in your `echo` statement.

```
<?php echo $this->__(" View Details about %s "), $_productNameStripped ?>
```

you are echoing `" View Details about %s "` followed by the variable. There is no syntax error, because you can pass multiple parameters to `echo`.

```
<?php echo $this->__(" View Details about %s ", $_productNameStripped); ?>
```